# Transform Object in Array with Jolt

Tags: arrays, json, object, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to convert a JSON object to an array contained one element

**Input** :

```
{
  "record": {
    "file_header": {
      "file_name": "TEST_FILE"
    },
    "scheda_contatto": {
      "phone_number": "5555-111-222-333",
      "type_call": 1
    }
  }
}
```

i want **scheda_contatto** to be an array with only 1 element

**Output**:

```
{
  "record": {
    "file_header": {
      "file_name": "TEST_FILE"
  },
  "scheda_contatto": [
    {
      "phone_number": "5555-111-222-333",
      "type_call": 1
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&1[0].&` in order to nest all innermost sub-elements(`&`) of the single object by square-brackets(`[0]`) with key name `scheda_contatto`(`&1` under `s*`) while prefixing each value identifier by `&1` and `&2` respectively in order to replicate the wrapper key name `record` for both such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "rec*": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "s*": {
          "*": "&2.&1[0].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry @barbaros-Özhan
but I found a problem that I don't know how to solve, in your solution you have deleted **record** , how can I not delete it?